# How to use java.util.scanner in android and java?

Tags: java, android

```
java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner("hello io am hgdh asgjdgh ghahgd").useDelimiter("\\A");
String S = s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
```

what contain value of S Variable?

Comment: Do you know java is case sensitive 's' is not similar to 'S'

Comment: @Sharpedge ,`s` is the `Scanner` and `S` is the `String` in OP's code

Comment: See how one can get confused with unformatted code.. didn't see the String at the end just a line beginning with a big S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

int i = sc.nextInt(); // for integer value
byte by = sc.nextByte(); // for Byte value
String s = sc.nextLine(); // for String value
```

You can find other method of Scanner class .[Scanner class Method](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/java_util_scanner.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for String Tokenizer http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-stringtokenizer-example/  have a look here....Happy Coding